# Recursion asymptotic growth function proof of complexity

Tags: recursion

I have the following recursive function(an example from a textbook):

$$
T(n)=\begin{cases}1&n=1\\T(\lfloor\tfrac n2\rfloor)+T(\lceil\tfrac n2\rceil)+1&n>1\end{cases}
$$

A recursion is used in order to prove that $T(n) = O(n)$

*The hypothesis is:*
for each $k$ such that $\lfloor\tfrac n2\rfloor\leq k\leq n-1$ we get: $T(k)\leq c\cdot k$

**My Question:** why did they take a region of $k$ rather than a single value of $k$, I mean why not say: for $k = \lfloor\tfrac n2\rfloor$ we get that $T(k)\leq c\cdot k$

Comment: The use of the terms *lower bound* and *upper bound* seems a bit confusing to me. Do you mean *floor function* and *ceiling function* so that it is $$T(n)=\begin{cases}1&n=1\\T(\lfloor\tfrac n2\rfloor)+T(\lceil\tfrac n2\rceil)+1&n>1\end{cases}$$

Comment: @String, yes exactly. i didn't know how to show it in the picture. excuse my humble skills, im still new member here :)

Comment: I formatted it for you - you can edit your post or right click on math expressions to see the $\TeX$-commands that I used. I hope my edit is OK!?

Comment: yes it's alright, thank you.